# Is this interpretation of signals correct?

Tags: c, signals, child-process, kill, waitpid

We are in a parent process, and *pid* holds the child process ID.
My question is, in this piece of code, are we just waiting for a stopped(WUNTRACED) / resumed(WCONTINUED) signal for the child process? Or we can accept a kill/stop signal as well?

```
waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
```

Comment: Read [`man 2 waitpid`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`waitpid()` always returns when the process has exited. Those flags make it *also* return when one of the specified conditions has occurred to the process.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know that